# Weighted average of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, variance, average

Suppose I have $n$ independent random variables $X_1,\dots, X_n$ drawn from a Bernoulli distribution with probability $p$. Furthermore, I have $n$ coefficients labeled $a_1,\dots, a_n$.

What is the expected value and variance for the following weighted average?

\begin{equation}
m=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}
\end{equation}

Since the random variables in the numerator and denominator are clearly correlated, I can not simply take the expected values independently, however, logically the expected value should equal to the mean $E[m] = \bar{a} =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$. How can I show that mathematically and how would I proceed to find the variance of $m$?

Thank you.

Comment: The denominator is zero

Comment: Asymptotically atleast, $m\to \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}$ almost surely if the RHS is finite by just using the strong law of large numbers. So your "logical" presumption should not really be true. as then it would have converged to $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}$ if this limit exists. Concluding $L^{1}$ convergence would follow once we show uniform integrability.

Comment: @AndrewZhang I think the op assumes that $m=0$ if each $X_{i}$'s are $0$.

Comment: Also @h2o2, perhaps you can add a bit more context to your problem. That is, is this a homework problem or a part of some proof or anything else, where did you encounter it etc

Answer (score 1):

As @Andrew Zhang mentions, $m$ is ill-defined if it happens that the realization of $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ is $(0, \dots, 0)$ as we then get $0$ in the denominator.

However, by formally setting $m$ in that situation to be $\bar{a} $, it actually turns out that $\mathbb{E}[m] = \bar{a}$.

This can be shown by brute-force calculation: As the $X_i$'s are independent, by grouping in the number of $X_i$'s that are $1$, we get

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[m] &= (1-p)^n \cdot \bar{a} + \sum_{k = 1}^n p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k} \cdot \left(\sum_{I \in [n]^{(k)}} \frac{\sum_{i \in I} a_i}{k}\right),\\
&= (1-p)^n \cdot \bar{a} + \sum_{k = 1}^n p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k} \cdot \frac{1}{k}\left(\sum_{I \in [n]^{(k)}} {\sum_{i \in I} a_i}\right),
\end{align}
where $[n]^{(k)}$ is the set of $k$-element subsets of $[n]= \{1,2, \dots, n\}$.

Let's analyze the inner term: We add $a_i$ for every $I \in [n]^{(k)}$ that contains $i$. There are exactly $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ such $I$'s, so

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{k}\sum_{I \in [n]^{(k)}} {\sum_{i \in I} a_i} &= \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \binom{n-1}{k-1} a_i \\
&=  \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \frac{(n-1)!}{((n-1)-(k-1))! (k-1)!}\cdot a_i \\
&= \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \frac{n!}{(n-k)! k!}\cdot \frac{a_i}{n} \\
&= \binom{n}{k}\cdot \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \frac{a_i}{n} \\
&= \binom{n}{k}\cdot \bar{a}.
\end{align}

Thus, using the Binomial Theorem, we get

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[m] &= \sum_{k = 0}^n p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k} \cdot \binom{n}{k}\cdot \bar{a} \\
&=  \bar{a}  \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k} p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k} \\
&= \bar{a}.
\end{align}

The variance can be calculated in a similar way:

\begin{align}
& & \mathbb{E}[m^2] &= (1-p)^n \cdot (\bar{a})^2 + \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{ p^k (1-p)^{n-k}}{k^2} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1} a_i^2 - 2 \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} \binom{n-2}{k-2} a_i a_j \right) \\
\implies{}& & \mathbb{V}(m) &= \mathbb{E}[m^2] - (\mathbb{E}[m])^2 \\
& & &= (1-p)^n \cdot (\bar{a})^2 + \sum_{k = 1}^n  \frac{ p^k (1-p)^{n-k}}{k^2} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1} a_i^2 - 2 \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} \binom{n-2}{k-2} a_i a_j \right) - (\bar{a})^2.
\end{align}